# Xamarin Android and file operations

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, filenotfoundexception

I'm faced with a problem. I'm trying to download a file and save it to external storage with `FileStream`. Here is my code:

```
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
    request.Method = "GET"; 
     using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            long length = responseStream.Length;                
            using (var stream = new FileStream(somePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)) // System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
            {
                while (true)
                {                   
                    var buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                    int bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);    
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        break;    
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);                              
                }
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // some code
}
```

As you can see I download the file and try to save it with the filename "somePath" and then I get `DirectoryNotFoundException` with the message `Could not find a part of the path "/mnt/sdcard/myFolder/tmp.mp3"`. 
Variable `somePath` has the following value: `/mnt/sdcard/myFolder/tmp.mp3`. 
Of course my application has `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. 
I have no idea how to solve this problem. Could you help me with it?

Comment: Does `/mnt/sdcard/myFolder` exist? A subdirectory like `myFolder` will not be auto-created, it needs to exists before creating your `FileStream`. i.e. use `Directory.CreateDirectory` or create a `java.io.File` and use the `mkdir` method (it will create any needed (parent) directories).

Comment: @SushiHangover yes directory exists